# For condition return 2 strings but printing only the last string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a for condition whit nested arrays , it works ok but it should display 2 strings but only show the last string

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.taskGroups.length; i++) {

                for (j = 0; j < $scope.taskGroups[i].tasks.length; j++) {

                    $scope.mandatories = $scope.taskGroups[i].tasks[j].mandatory;

                    if ($scope.mandatories === true) {
                         $scope.display =$scope.taskGroups[i].tasks[j].name
                         console.log($scope.display);   
                    }

                }

            }
```

console log

```
routes_init.js:60 Destaques extra linear
routes_init.js:60 Equipamentos de frio
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "_should display 2 strings but only show the last string_" In the output you showed us there are 2 different strings so I am confused.

Comment: @csmckelvey yes but it should be only in one line , that why its showing only the last one

Comment: Then you need to build a string inside your loop instead of logging inside your loop. Once the loop is done you can just log the string one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by doing this

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.taskGroups.length; i++) {


            for (j = 0; j < $scope.taskGroups[i].tasks.length; j++) {

                $scope.mandatories = $scope.taskGroups[i].tasks[j].mandatory;

                if ($scope.mandatories === true) {

                    $scope.display =$scope.taskGroups[i].tasks[j].name;

                    mandatory = $scope.display.split(",").concat(mandatory).filter(function(n){return n !== undefined});


                }
                $scope.mandatorys = mandatory;
                console.log($scope.mandatorys) 
            }


        }
```